# Dumping data reported by client to server to a Log file

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I'm using WCF services in the client application for transfering data from client to server and vice-versa. I'm looking for a mechanism to log the data sent to server into the log file on client machine. I looked into the WCF library but could not find any code which serializes the WCF requests. Logging no issues, I use N-Log for that but I don't find any built in function which gives the webrequest data.

My question is, is there any built in support for getting the webrequest details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in option is called [Message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) but this option uses its own way to log messages using standard .NET trace listeners.

If you want custom message logger you have to implement [your own logging endpoint behavior with IClientMessageInspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx).